# Why does this code return a nonsensical cell address

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

So, I have this bit of code in my program

```
Sheets("Produtos").Select

Dim codigo As Integer
Dim xCell As String

codigo = Text_CodPro.Text

xCell = Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(codigo, Range("B3:B3000"), 0)).Address
Planilha1.Range("A3").Select
ActiveCell.Value = xCell
```

It should find me the address of a cell that is, for example, in B6, instead, it says the match address is D1, an empty cell. For the life of me I can't figure out what I did wrong here.

Comment: If you index into `Cells` (ie. the whole worksheet) then it goes row-by-row, so the 5th cell is E1 for example.

Comment: You're passing a single argument to `Cells`. Try adding `"B"` or `2` as the 2nd argument.

Comment: That was it, BigBen, thanks! It is not returning B4 but I know why (it starts at B3 so is counting from there, I just need to adjust) :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - a few suggestions for changes in the code

```vb
Dim rngSrch As Range
Dim codigo As Long   'prefer Long over Integer
Dim m As Variant     'so you can capture an error value if there's no match

Set rngSrch = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Produtos").Range("B3:B3000")

codigo = 3 'CLng(Text_CodPro.Text) 'convert to Long

m = Application.Match(codigo, rngSrch, 0) 'no `Worksheetfunction` = no run-time error if no match

If Not IsError(m) Then 'got a match?
    Planilha1.Range("A3").Value = rngSrch.Cells(m).Address
Else
    MsgBox "no match for " & codigo
End If
```

Comment: Just as additional hint: Since Match returns a number if the search is successful, it is also possible to formulate the suggested error check positively: **`If IsNumeric(m) Then`** instead of *`If Not IsError(m) Then`*.